# C++ OpenGL, drawing shapes is returning an error

Tags: c++, opengl, glad

I am trying to draw shapes onto my application. I have added `#include <glad/glad.h>` into my code.

I set my vertex array, vertex buffer & index buffer as unsigned ints in my header file.

In my *application.h* file I added this:

```
unsigned int m_FCvertexArray; // Textured Phong VAO
unsigned int m_FCvertexBuffer;// Textured Phong VBO
unsigned int m_FCindexBuffer; // Index buffer for texture Phong cube
```

In my application.cpp in my constructor I added this:

```
Application::Application()
{
    //------------- OPENGL VALUES -----------//

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    // Enabling backface culling to ensure triangle vertices are correct ordered (CCW)

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    ////--------DRAW VERTICES---------//

    float FCvertices[3 * 3] = {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
            };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_FCvertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(m_FCvertexArray);

    glCreateBuffers(1, &m_FCvertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_FCvertexBuffer);

    //
    //

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(FCvertices), FCvertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(sizeof(float) * 3));


    ////--------DRAW INDICES---------//

    glCreateBuffers(1, &m_FCindexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_FCindexBuffer);

    unsigned int indices[3] = {0, 1, 2};

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

in my `void Application::run()` I added:

```
glUseProgram(m_FCprogram);
glBindVertexArray(m_FCvertexArray);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

now the problem is when I run the code, it gives me the error mentioned on the title:

[Exception thrown at 0x000000005D78F420 (nvoglv64.dll) in Sandbox.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32H3G.png)

I've been trying ways to fix this but it seems not to work. and if i comment out glDrawElements, the code runs and works but no shapes are drawn (obvious).

Comment: Do you call `gladLoadGLLoader`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 where do i call it, and what do i write?

Comment: See [glad](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#glad_.28Multi-Language_GL.2FGLES.2FEGL.2FGLX.2FWGL_Loader-Generator.29)

Answer (score -1):

When you create the index buffer, you need to use GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER instead of GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.